# Why do we add mustard to egg mix when making Schnitzel?

Tags: eggs, breadcrumbs

So far I got,

1. The flour gives somethigng that egg can stick too
2. The egg wash layer acts as something which the bread crumbs stick too

But, why mix in the mustard to the egg? Couldn't the egg wash directly stick to breadcrumbs?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a recipe for schnitzel with mustard added at that step. Flavour is likely to be the answer, added with the egg as liquid; could probably add as powder with the flour instead.

Answer (score 7):

Mustard has an intense flavor and is therefore generally added in quantities that have very little effect on consistency, stickiness and similar things. Your recipe aparently wanted to introduce mustard flavor. If you agree keep it in, otherwise you can leave it out without any further adjustments.